# Spring-Boot: configure Log4j2 to use Spring-Boot DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, log4j2

I'm building an application using **Spring-Boot** (*1.5.9-RELEASE*) and I want to use **log4j2** with it.

I want to configure **log4j2** to log to a database table using a JDBC connection.

My issue is that I am unable to configure **log4j2** to use the **DataSource** I have configured for **Spring-Boot**.

I know that **log4j2** starts-up before Spring-Boot does, so I've put some code in which, after **Spring-Boot** is loaded, it has log4j2 re-configure itself.

My issue is that I can't get an instance of a **DataSource** from **Spring-Boot**.

I'm not very familiar with dependency injection but I'm assuming that since I need **Spring-Boot** to inject the **DataSource**, the way that I'm creating an instance of **DBUtils** is not going to work.
But since **log4j2** needs a static method which provides a **Connection**, I'm not sure how to get this to work.

---

### Question

1) Can someone explain how I can have **log4j2** use **Spring-Boot**s DataSource?
Or do I have to create a new connection pool in **DBUtils** and have log4j2 use that pool?

---

### Spring-Boot Config

I've included the **spring-boot-starter-log4j2** dependency and excluded the default Spring-Boot logger **spring-boot-starter-logging**.

### Part of application.properties

```
spring.datasource.name=mainDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=---a valid JDBC URL---
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true

logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml
```

The url is valid, I'm just not posting it online :p

### JDBC Appender from log4j2.xml

```
<Jdbc
    name="DatabaseAppender"
    tableName="pws_logs">
    <ConnectionFactory
        class="com.test.utils.DBUtils"
        method="getConnection" />
    <Column
        name="log_date"
        isEventTimestamp="true" />
    <Column
        name="log_level"
        pattern="%-5level" />
    <Column
        name="logger"
        pattern="%40.40logger" />
    <Column
        name="line_num"
        pattern="%line" />
    <Column
        name="message"
        pattern="%message" />
    <Column
        name="throwable"
        pattern="%throwable"
        isClob="true" />
</Jdbc>
```

### DBUtils

```
package com.test.utils;

import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DBUtils {

    private static DBUtils dbUtils = null;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mainDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        return DBUtils.getDBUtils().getSingleConnection();
    }

    private static DBUtils getDBUtils() {
        if (DBUtils.dbUtils == null) {
            DBUtils.dbUtils = new DBUtils();
        }

        return DBUtils.dbUtils;
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
        if (this.dataSource == null) {
            logger.error("Spring-Boot failed to inject database datasource.");
        }

        return this.dataSource;
    }

    private Connection getSingleConnection() throws Exception {
        try {
            return this.getDataSource().getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to get database connection.", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

### Entry Point Class

```
package com.test;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PaymentWsApplication {

    private static Logger logger = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public static void initLogger() {
        final LoggerContext loggerContext = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
        loggerContext.reconfigure();

        PaymentWsApplication.logger = LogManager.getLogger(PaymentWsApplication.class);

        logger.info("********************** Application  started-up.");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PaymentWsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any update on this? I have a similar issue..

Comment: I recently found a post that showed how to add the JdbcAppender programatically. It requires that you create your own connection pool, but it works perfectly. http://smasue.github.io/log4j2-spring-database-appender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue. It's not perfect, as it doesn't use the Spring Boot connection pool, but it works for me.

http://smasue.github.io/log4j2-spring-database-appender

**The steps are:**

1. create @Configuration class which executes below steps during @PostConstruction
2. extract the database configuration from the Spring Boot properties
3. create a connection pool programatically
4. create the JdbcAppender and add it to the root logger.